# Type or namespace 'DocumentFormat' could not be found - only on build - but intellisense shows the type as available

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have downloaded the `Power Tools for Open XML` from the following website:-

https://powertools.codeplex.com/

I open the solution in VS2012 and then update the references - `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` and `WindowsBase`.

The problem is:-

The Visual Studio intellisense shows the namespace when I start typing it at the top of class, but when I build the solution, I get the following error from all the classes where this namespace is used-

`The type or namespace 'DocumentFormat' could not be found.`

Comment: My crystal ball says that your project is targeting the .NET Client profile.  Change it to the full version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements and environment, you need to ***match*** the **PowerTools** and **OpenXML SDK** versions.

**PowerTools 2.2** (which right now is the default download on *codeplex*) uses **DocumentFormat.OpenXml** version *2.0.5022.0* which comes with **OpenXml SDK 2.0**.
This project is built on *.NET Framework 3.5*.

**PowerTools for OpenXML 3.0 version 3.*** (also available to download at https://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771) uses **DocumentFormat.OpenXml** version *2.5.5631.0* which comes with **OpenXml SDK 2.5**.
 This project is built on *.NET Framework 4.0+*.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone else still facing issue, as was i.

Go to nuget package manager and search openxml and install from there.